# How to trust all hosts using Android DownloadManager with https

Tags: android, ssl

I am using DownloadManager to download a file from a https server in my android app. As I'm still in the development phase, I would like to trust all hosts and avoid certificate checks. How can I tell DownloadManager to trust all hosts?

For further development, how can I add a certificate to trust a certain host with DownloadManager?

Thank you.

Comment: If you don't want it secure why are you using HTTPS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Android Nougat and newer you can use the declarative Network Security Config to make the app trust a particular leaf or CA certificate used by that server -- see https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.html#ConfigCustom for an example. Download Manager will trust that certificate for HTTPS requests on behalf of your app as well.