# Xamarin WebView download doesn't work for Mp4Upload

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a small Xamarin form app that I want to use to download files from mp4Upload. This is done by loading the mp4Upload url onto a `WebView` and then programmatically clicking the download button using `WebView.EvaluateJavascriptAsync()`.

The problem is that it doesn't trigger a download.

```cs
public class AndroidWebView : WebViewRenderer
{
    public AndroidWebView(Context ctx) : base(ctx)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.WebView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control != null)
        {
            Control.Settings.UserAgentString = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0";
        }

        Control.Download += DownloadEvent;
    }

    private void DownloadEvent(object sender, Android.Webkit.DownloadEventArgs e)
    {
        string url = e.Url;
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Android.Net.Uri.Parse(url));
        request.SetNotificationVisibility(DownloadVisibility.VisibleNotifyCompleted);
        request.SetDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads, "CPPPrimer");
        DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService("download");
        dm.Enqueue(request);
        Toast.MakeText(Android.App.Application.Context, e.Url, ToastLength.Long).Show();
    }
}
```

I've tested the above code with a github url to download a random .gitignore file which works fine.

The mp4Upload link also works in chrome if I manually click download as well as working on winforms using cefsharp using `ChromiumWebBrowser.ExecuteScriptAsync()` to programmatically click download.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It's not as simple as it looks, especially for downloads that open in a `_blank` target. This is the code I used in one of my projects:

1. Setup your webview to support downloads:

```cs
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Android.Webkit;
using Android.Content;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

// In your android webview renderer
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<XamWebView> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);
    if (this.Control != null)
    {
        var xamWebView = (AppWebView)e.NewElement;
        this.AllowFileDownloads(this.Control, xamWebView);
    }
    }

private void AllowFileDownloads(DroidWebView webView, AppWebView customWebView)
{
    webView.Settings.SetSupportMultipleWindows(false);
    var downloadListener = new WebViewDownloadListener(this.Context);
    webView.SetDownloadListener(downloadListener);
}
```

2. Use this as your webview download listener

```cs
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Webkit;
using Android.Content;
using Xamarin.Essentials;

public class WebViewDownloadListener : Java.Lang.Object, IDownloadListener
{
    private Context AppContext { get; }
    public event Action<string> OnDownloadStarted;

    private DownloadManager DownloadManager => DownloadManager.FromContext(this.AppContext);

    public WebViewDownloadListener(Context appContext)
    {
        this.AppContext = appContext;
        this.AppContext.RegisterReceiver(new OnDownloadCompleteOpenFileInDefaultApp(), new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ActionDownloadCom
    }

    public void OnDownloadStart(string url, string userAgent, string contentDisposition, string mimetype, long contentLength)
    {
        this.OnDownloadStarted?.Invoke(url);
        var downloadRequest = BuildDownloadRequest(url, userAgent, contentDisposition, mimetype);
        AppErrorHandler.ExecuteSafely(async () =>
        {
            if (ShouldAskPermissionToSaveFile)
            {
                var permission = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.StorageWrite>();
                if (permission == PermissionStatus.Granted)
                    this.EnqueueDownloadRequest(downloadRequest);
            }
            else
                this.EnqueueDownloadRequest(downloadRequest);
        });
    }

    private static bool ShouldAskPermissionToSaveFile => Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt <= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.P;

    private void EnqueueDownloadRequest(DownloadManager.Request downloadRequest)
    {
        this.DownloadManager.Enqueue(downloadRequest);
        Toast.MakeText(this.AppContext, "Downloading File", ToastLength.Long).Show();
    }

    private static DownloadManager.Request BuildDownloadRequest(string url, string userAgent, string contentDisposition, string mimetype)
    {
        var request = new DownloadManager.Request(Android.Net.Uri.Parse(url));
        request.SetMimeType(mimetype);
        request.SetDescription("Downloading file...");
        request.AddRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
        request.AddRequestHeader("cookie", CookieManager.Instance.GetCookie(url));
        request.SetNotificationVisibility(DownloadVisibility.VisibleNotifyCompleted);
        request.SetDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
            Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads, 
            URLUtil.GuessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype)
        );
        return request;
    }
}
```

3. And finally, this as your download broadcast receiver

```cs
using Java.IO;
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Database;
using AndroidX.Core.Content;

public class OnDownloadCompleteOpenFileInDefaultApp : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if (DownloadManager.ActionDownloadComplete.Equals(intent.Action))
        {
            ICursor cursor = GetDbCursorForDownloadedFile(context, intent);
            if (cursor.MoveToFirst())
            {
                var (downloadStatus, downloadUri, mimeType) = ExtractDataFromCursor(cursor);
                if (downloadStatus == (int)DownloadStatus.Successful && downloadUri != null)
                {
                    var fileUri = GetFileUri(context, downloadUri);
                    var openFileIntent = CreateOpenFileIntent(mimeType, fileUri);
                    LaunchOpenFileIntent(context, openFileIntent);
                }
            }
            cursor.Close();
        }
    }

    private static ICursor GetDbCursorForDownloadedFile(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        var downloadManager = DownloadManager.FromContext(context);
        var downloadId = intent.GetLongExtra(DownloadManager.ExtraDownloadId, 0);
        var query = new DownloadManager.Query();
        query.SetFilterById(downloadId);
        var cursor = downloadManager.InvokeQuery(query);
        return cursor;
    }

    private static (int status, string downloadUri, string mimeType) ExtractDataFromCursor(ICursor cursor) =
    (
        cursor.GetInt(cursor.GetColumnIndex(DownloadManager.ColumnStatus)),
        cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(DownloadManager.ColumnLocalUri)),
        cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(DownloadManager.ColumnMediaType))
    );

    private static Android.Net.Uri GetFileUri(Context context, string downloadUri)
    {
        var fileUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(downloadUri);
        if (ContentResolver.SchemeFile.Equals(fileUri.Scheme))
        {
            // FileUri - Convert it to contentUri.
            File file = new File(fileUri.Path);
            fileUri = FileProvider.GetUriForFile(context, $"{context.PackageName}.fileprovider", file);
        }
        return fileUri;
    }

    private static Intent CreateOpenFileIntent(string mimeType, Android.Net.Uri fileUri)
    {
        Intent openAttachmentIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
        openAttachmentIntent.SetDataAndType(fileUri, mimeType);
        openAttachmentIntent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
        return openAttachmentIntent;
    }

    private static void LaunchOpenFileIntent(Context context, Intent openAttachmentIntent)
    {
        try
        {
            context.StartActivity(openAttachmentIntent);
        }
        catch (ActivityNotFoundException)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(context, "Could not open file.", ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `this.AllowFileDownloads` doesnt exist apparently... What version of xamarin is this on?

Comment: nvm I misread your code xD my bad

Comment: The method is defined in the same code block

Comment: What is `AppErrorHandler`?

Comment: Some error catching code, you can ignore that and remove from the code snippet.

Comment: Your solution still doesn't work for mp4Upload links, I did some digging around and I think it may be something to do with how mp4upload manages access to their files. When you click the download button mp4upload creates a post request to itself with some parameters which then redirects to the download. This post request however only works if done by mp4upload. This means you can't make a post request from outside of mp4upload otherwise the request comes back as forbidden. This is fine, but then how am I still able to download on chrome through mp4upload and cefsharp as well??

Comment: What is mp4upload?

Comment: Its a site that holds videos, I wish to scrape it and download some videos from it.

Comment: Ok, well sorry my code didn't help. I can't help you more without a concrete example.

Comment: If you want an example link then https://www.mp4upload.com/gfofc1pr590c. If you're visiting the site via browser I recommend turning off javascript to avoid ads unless you have an ad blocker. Currently my code just programmatically clicks the download buttons to trigger the download event.

Comment: Ok, I know what your problem is. The download button sends you to this URL:
https://www3.mp4upload.com:282/d/r2xvixg3z3b4quuofwqb2ncpi42hkswnbaaw3akq2yu6uy22iilfppam/[MK]%20Assassination%20Classroom%20-%2001%20[BD%201080p][Hi10][Dual%20Audio]%20[73C01703].mp4 which doesn't have a valid HTTPS certificate. To the best of my knowledge, I don't know how to make DownloadManager trust invalid SSL certificates.

Comment: This post should help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41118412/how-to-trust-all-hosts-using-android-downloadmanager-with-https

Comment: I'm not sure if thats completely the issue because the url that mp4upload provides changes each time you click it. If you try to use the link on its own in browser it fails, however if you run it in a redirect from the mp4upload domain it works (in developer console type `window.location.replace("https://www3.mp4upload.com:282/d/r2xvixg3z3b4quuofwqb2ncpi42hkswnbaaw3akq2yu6uy22iilfppam/[MK]%20Assassination%20Classroom%20-%2001%20[BD%201080p][Hi10][Dual%20Audio]%20[73C01703].mp4");`)

Comment: Look into android log cat, filter logs with "DownloadManager", and you'll see, it's a certificate error.